SPRESENSEメインボードでUARTを2ch使いたいです。
SPRESENSEメインボード1個でUARTを2ch使いたいです。
1chは、PIN SOCKET [L] (JP1)の2,3番ピンを使います。
もう1chは、他のI/Oピンを2ピン(TX,RX)使って、ソフトウェアUARTで実現できないかと調べているのですが、わからない状況です。
教えていただけますと助かります。
よろしくお願いいたします。

SPRESENSE公式ページに解説がありますよ。
Software Serial ライブラリ
https://developer.sony.com/spresense/development-guides/arduino_developer_guide_ja.html#_software_serial_%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%96%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA
SoftwareSerial Class Reference
https://developer.sony.com/spresense/spresense-api-references-arduino/classSoftwareSerial.html
